# Replacing commented line in bash file using sed fails

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I am trying to update my `hadoop-env.sh` file such that I replace a commented parameter with a new one. I am new to the whole concept and after a lot of searching I ended up doing the following:

```
sed -i '/^export JAVA_HOME=/ s:.*:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\nexport HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop\n:' $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

The part of file that I am trying to update looks like:

```
# The java implementation to use. By default, this environment
# variable is REQUIRED on ALL platforms except OS X!
# export JAVA_HOME=
```

And desired outcome is:

```
# The java implementation to use. By default, this environment
# variable is REQUIRED on ALL platforms except OS X!
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
```

However, when I cat the `hadoop-env.sh` file I am getting the same content as before. I have to mention that I am running this in `Dockerfile` using the following:

```
RUN sed -i '/^export JAVA_HOME=/ s:.*:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\nexport HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop\n:' $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

I have no idea what I might be missing and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is because there is not any line in your file starting with `export JAVA_HOME=` .                 
 The desired line starts with `# export ` so the anchor in sed `/^export` matches nothing. You need to modify it accordingly to catch `# export`

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in the comments.

Change:

`sed -i '/^export JAVA_HOME=/ s:.*:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\nexport HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop\n:' $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`

To: (adds 2 characters only)

`sed -i '/^# export JAVA_HOME=/ s:.*:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64\nexport HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop\n:' $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`